# Should we limit links for new users?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I am a new user, and struggling to cite references because users with less than 10 rep points are limited to posting only 2 links. I can see why this policy is in place, to prevent anonymous users/bots continually self promoting and trying to use the site as a means for boosting google ranking. Is there any way to get around this policy for the purpose of posting citations? I have removed the HTTP and just put the link in the text, but that is ugly and seems self promotional even when it may not be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange and its stupid policies. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for making the effort to post answers with good references that are linked for the convenience of our users. While this is a somewhat annoying restriction, it is SE-wide and would probably need to be addressed on [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and implemented across all beta sites in order for a change in policy to be a possibility here. Please consider weighing in at a related question on Meta.SE:

[Does restricting the number of links for new users do any good?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122893/272257)

In the meantime, if you (well, no longer applicable to *you* [since you have crossed rep=10](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)) have additional links you would like to post prior to gaining the requisite rep, feel free to post a comment with the links below your post and someone will likely move them for you if they are appropriate. Alternatively, you could visit our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22477/the-waiting-room) and request help.

**Update**: it is possible to lift this restriction. However, given the possibility of increased volume of incorrectly represented references, this may not be a good idea for this site. If anyone would like to make a case that the benefits of this change would outweigh this concern, please write an answer for the community to vote on.

Comment: I think putting them in the comments would be a good work around. It would prove the person has the right intent and get them involved at the same time.

Comment: and you can flag the mods to quickly move the link to the answer section

Comment: You can simply ask SE to increase the limit. I'm not sure if they'd grant the request, but we successfully did this on Skeptics a while ago

Comment: @MadScientist  Oh sheesh, I probably should have read all the way to the last line. I hadn't even seen the final update. That was already a graduated site, though?

Comment: @Susan Yes, but that doesn't matter. I had to annoy the SE team for months to get this changed, but it should be much simpler for anyone else now